# WordPress Screwing Up 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' in 'pre_get_posts'

Tags: meta-query, order, pre-get-posts, meta-value

I have a bunch of `_ai_price_int` meta values set up as just numbers. This is how the table looks:

```
meta_id, post_id, meta_key,      meta_value
1309,    1111,    _ai_price_int, 6550
1310,    1115,    _ai_price_int, 7100
1311,    1113,    _ai_price_int, 7500
1312,    1103,    _ai_price_int, 6000
etc.
```

I'm using a `pre_get_posts` filter to modify a particular query, like this:

```
public function filterQuery($query) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'sponsorship');
    $query->set('meta_key', '_ai_price_int');
    $query->set('meta_value', '4000');
    $query->set('meta_compare', '<=');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', Array($this, 'filterQuery'));
```

But playing around with `$query->set('meta_value', '4000');`, it turns out that the results are incorrect.

- When using `2000`, I'm getting a post that has an _ai_price_int value of `15000`.
- When using `4000`, I'm getting a post that has an _ai_price_int value of `35000`.

I tried using:

```
    $query->set('post_type', 'sponsorship');
    $query->set('meta_key', '_ai_price_int');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
           'key' => '_ai_price_int',
           'value' => array(0, 4000),
           'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    ));
```

instead, but the results are the same.

Looking at the performed query, I can see that it has this portion:

```
...AND ((wp_13postmeta.meta_key = '_ai_price_int'AND CAST(wp_13postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) <= '4000') )...
```

**Don't tell me that WordPress is ordering these values alphabetically?!**

I'm also saving this custom value as an integer explicitly:

```
$price = (int)preg_replace("/([^0-9\\.])/i", "", $match[1]);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ai_price_int', $price );
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm testing on WP version: 3.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `meta_query` and set `type` to `NUMERIC`-

```
$query->set('meta_query', array(
    array(
       'key' => '_ai_price_int',
       'value' => array(0, 4000),
       'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
       'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )
));
$query->set('meta_key', '_ai_price_int');
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
```

Comment: oh nice, I hadn't seen that. is there a difference in results between using `'type'  => 'NUMERIC'` in the meta_query and just setting the meta_value as a number using `$query->set('meta_value_num', '4000');` ?

Comment: `meta_query` is the newer way to handle custom field queries and is more flexible than the older `meta_` arguments, for the sake of consistency I just stick with the newer API stuff. The older way may work just as well, though I haven't actually tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to change `$query->set('meta_value', '4000');` to `$query->set('meta_value_num', '4000');` in your pre_get_posts filter.

The WP_Query docs note that:

> "By using the 'meta_value' parameter the value 99 will be considered
>   greater than 100 as the data are stored as 'strings', not 'numbers'.
>   For number comparison use 'meta_value_num'."

from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters